# Remove Certain AppPool based on input Array in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to display whether the AppPool for IIS is started or not.
By default it will display all AppPool State.

But if a parameter -EA (--exceptionAppPool) is passed while running the script it will not consider the status of those AppPool.

I am somehow stuck with the else{} statement when -EA is passed. Not sure how to remove the list of array passed in -EA from being considered in Get-WebAppPoolState method

```
param([String[]]$EA)
if (-Not ($ParamAvailable = $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('EA'))){
    $ApplicationPoolsState = Get-WebAppPoolState | % {  return  @{($_.itemxpath -split ("'"))[1]="$($_.value)" } } | % getEnumerator | % {
        if ($_.value -ne "Started"){
            $statuses.critical += $_.key
        }
        else{
            $statuses.ok += $_.key
        }
    }
}
else{
      #----I want to exclude the Keys which is present in -EA array ?
      #----The example of -EA is .NET v4.5,.NET v4.5 Classic,DefaultAppPool
      $ApplicationPoolsState = Get-WebAppPoolState | % {  return  @{($_.itemxpath -split ("'"))[1]="$($_.value)" } }
      for ($i=0; $i -lt $EA.length; $i++){
          $ApplicationPoolsState = $ApplicationPoolsState.Remove($EA[$i])
      }
      $ApplicationPoolsState = $ApplicationPoolsState | % getEnumerator | % {
      if ($_.value -ne "Started"){  
           $statuses.critical += $_.key
      }
      else{
        $statuses.ok += $_.key
    }
}
```

script will run like .\check_appPool.ps1 -EA .NET v4.5,.NET v4.5 Classic,DefaultAppPool

Got error

> Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a
> fixed size."

How do I exclude those from being checked in the else statement

Comment: One way to remove an object from a fixed-size array is to create a new array that includes only selected objects from the original array. There is a solution to this kind of problem in this blog, you can refer to it: https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-tips-tricks/removing-objects-from-arrays-in-powershell

Comment: Thank You Very much. That solved my problem

Comment: Congratulations! I will post it as a reply, and you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to remove an object from a fixed-size array is to create a new array that includes only selected objects from the original array. There is a solution to this kind of problem in this blog, you can refer to [it](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-tips-tricks/removing-objects-from-arrays-in-powershell).